# In an Ubuntu "open file" dialog, how to sort in alphabetical order by default?

Tags: ubuntu

I just cannot find any way to just set the alphabetical order in an "open file" dialog in Ubuntu.

Here is my problem : I use Libreoffice on Ubuntu. In Libreoffice, the relevant parameter is set on "system file dialog" (instead of "Libreoffice dialog").

Each time I want to open a file, the dialog box sorts file in a chronological order.
I can click on the "name" column title to sort by name, but it is annoying to do this every time.

Any idea?

Edit: this problem of course only happens with Ubuntu. Whether it is on Mac OS X or Windows, the "open file" dialog displays, by default, files sorted by alphabetical order.

Comment: Hi! Your question is fine, it just hasn't been viewed that often. Maybe there's some additional info you found after posting this? You can [edit] your post and add some details – this will put your question on the front page again. (But in the future, please don't flag for attention unless something needs moderator intervention. Thanks!)